# Wordpress plugin admin_notices not displaying

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm trying to create a Wordpress plugin and I'm unable to display error messages using the `admin_notices` feature.

```php
function gbrew_notice_no_api_key() {
    $url = admin_url('admin.php') . '?page=api-key';
    ?>
    <div class="notice-info notice">
        <p><?php _e("Please set up your client ID and client secret from the <a href='{$url}'>API Key</a> page first."); ?></p>
    </div>
    <?php
}

function gbrew_setup_menu() {
    # Add the main menu option
    add_menu_page('Spruce Beer Dashboard', 'Spruce Beer', 'manage_options', 'spruce-beer', 'gbrew_dashboard');

    # Add the sub menu item to manage API keys
    add_submenu_page('spruce-beer', 'API Key', 'API Key', 'manage_options', 'api-key', 'gbrew_manage_api_key');
}
 
function gbrew_dashboard() {
    $client_id = get_option('untappd_client_id');
    $client_secret = get_option('untappd_client_secret');

    echo "<h1>Spruce Beer</h1>";

    if(!empty($client_id) && !empty($client_secret)) {
        var_dump($client_id);
        var_dump($client_secret);
    } else {
        add_action('admin_notices', 'gbrew_notice_no_api_key');
    }
}

# Add the plugin to the sidebar menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'gbrew_setup_menu');
```

Answer (score 1):

already I think in your first function you can do better to return the HTML and maybe that will fix your problem

```
function gbrew_notice_no_api_key() {
    $url = admin_url('admin.php') . '?page=api-key';
    return <<<HTML
    <div class="notice-info notice">
        <p>Please set up your client ID and client secret from the <a href='$url'>API Key</a> page first.</p>
    </div>
HTML;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll just use this solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your calling notices too late, they fire before admin_menu; try this

```
function gbrew_notice_no_api_key()
{
    $client_id = get_option('untappd_client_id');
    $client_secret = get_option('untappd_client_secret');
    if (empty($client_id) && empty($client_secret)) {
        $url = admin_url('admin.php') . '?page=api-key';
        ?>
        <div class="notice notice-success is-dismissible">
            <p><?php
                _e("Please set up your client ID and client secret from the <a href='{$url}'>API Key</a> page first."); ?></p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
}

function gbrew_setup_menu()
{
    # Add the main menu option
    add_menu_page('Spruce Beer Dashboard', 'Spruce Beer', 'manage_options', 'spruce-beer', 'gbrew_dashboard');

    # Add the sub menu item to manage API keys
    add_submenu_page('spruce-beer', 'API Key', 'API Key', 'manage_options', 'api-key', 'gbrew_manage_api_key');
}

function gbrew_dashboard()
{
    $client_id = get_option('untappd_client_id');
    $client_secret = get_option('untappd_client_secret');

    echo "<h1>Spruce Beer</h1>";

    if ( ! empty($client_id) && ! empty($client_secret)) {
        var_dump($client_id);
        var_dump($client_secret);
    } else {
        echo "<p>No Api Key Exists";
    }
}

# Add the plugin to the sidebar menu
add_action('admin_menu', 'gbrew_setup_menu');
add_action('admin_notices', 'gbrew_notice_no_api_key');
```

If your also running multisite, might be worth adding: `add_action('network_admin_notices', 'gbrew_notice_no_api_key');` as well

Comment: Not sure I'm liking this solution. I don't understand why there's a `echo "<p>No Api Key Exists";` and a call to show a notice with `add_action('admin_notices', 'gbrew_notice_no_api_key')`. My intentions was for those to be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that the problem is in the `gbrew_dashboard` function.

```php
function gbrew_dashboard() {
    $client_id = get_option('untappd_client_id');
    $client_secret = get_option('untappd_client_secret');

    echo "<h1>Spruce Beer</h1>";

    if(!empty($client_id) && !empty($client_secret)) {
        var_dump($client_id);
        var_dump($client_secret);
    } else {
        add_action('admin_notices', 'gbrew_notice_no_api_key');
    }
}
```

In the `else` statement you add `gbrew_notice_no_api_key` to `admin_notices`, but ***the action is never called***. Read [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/337818/208483) about how `do_action` and `add_action` work in tandem. In summary,

> The `do_action()` function executes any code that's been hooked with `add_action()`.

I think the simplest solution looks like this:

```php
function gbrew_dashboard() {
    $client_id = get_option('untappd_client_id');
    $client_secret = get_option('untappd_client_secret');

    echo "<h1>Spruce Beer</h1>";

    if(!empty($client_id) && !empty($client_secret)) {
        var_dump($client_id);
        var_dump($client_secret);
    } else {
        do_action('admin_notices');
    }
}

add_action('admin_notices', 'gbrew_notice_no_api_key');
```

Add `gbrew_notice_no_api_key` to the action no matter what, then call it with [`do_action`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/).

### You could use a custom action (optional)

However, keep in mind that if you call `do_action('admin_notices')`, **your plugin will call every function hooked to `admin_notices`, *even if they belong to other plugins***.

If you are not OK with that, then you could [add a custom action](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/custom-hooks/) instead. Taking `gbrew` as a prefix to [uniquely identify your own hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/hooks/custom-hooks/#naming-conflicts), you could **add a custom action that will be called only by your plugin**. In that case, your code would look like this:

```php
function gbrew_dashboard() {
    $client_id = get_option('untappd_client_id');
    $client_secret = get_option('untappd_client_secret');

    echo "<h1>Spruce Beer</h1>";

    if(!empty($client_id) && !empty($client_secret)) {
        var_dump($client_id);
        var_dump($client_secret);
    } else {
        // calling your custom action here!!!
        do_action('gbrew_admin_notices');
    }
}

add_action('gbrew_admin_notices', 'gbrew_notice_no_api_key');
```